# How do I recall method daily even after reboot?

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, scheduled-tasks

I know that I cam schedule method with Task.Delay, How do I recall method if PC / application was turned off at the time?

For example, if I scheduled the method at 18.00 and my PC is on, the method is called, if PC / application is turned off at the time, the method would be called when I boot up my PC / start the program.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things:

1. You need to persist the event information somewhere, e.g. a database or a flat file in the filesystem. This information will have to include the date and time you wish the event to fire and any parameters that it requires.
2. You need some way of starting your program automatically after a reboot. For example, you could run a bootstrapper program as a [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Windows%20services%2C%20formerly%20known,not%20show%20any%20user%20interface.), or launch the application using [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save this last time somewere (in file or even `app.config`) and read it when your application starts.

In `app.config` file, for example, you should add new key-value setting:

```
    <add key="lastRecallTime" value="2021.07.06 01:02:03" />
```

To save last `DateTime` value use this method (where key would be "lastRecallTime"):

```
    private void SetAppConfig(string key, string value)
    {
        Configuration configuration = 
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
        configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
    }
```

To read value from `app.config`:

```
    DateTime lastRecallTime = DateTime.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["lastRecallTime"]);
```